Delphi try except e.message - "e" class type expected
I got lost, it's not working for me. Error is
class type expected.
"message" undefined.

SysUtils is in place.
In a sample dpr, it's working fine. I did not find differences to my project.
try
  Connect;
except
  Memo1.text := e.message;
end; 


well, e isn't defined is it? You didn't declare it, so it's not a thing

"checked all hints in www" - please refrain from programming. And internet searches.

Strange... A web search on Delphi exceptions returns many results that have examples that show you the proper way to do this, and would easily show you what is wrong with your code. I must use a different version of Google than you do. What century is your internet from?

If you want to access the exception object, your except block needs an on clause to declare the e variable and the exception type it will catch, eg:
try
  Connect;
except
  on e: Exception do
    Memo1.text := e.message;
end;

SysUtils.Exception is the base class for all exception classes, so this example above will catch every exception that is derived from Exception. But you can also specify a specific derived class if you want, eg:
try
  Connect;
except
  on e: ESomeException do
    ...
end;

Any exception that is not derived from that type will not be caught here.
You can also specify multiple on clauses if you want to handle different types of exceptions, eg:
try
  Connect;
except
  on e: ESomeException do
    ...
  on e: EOtherException do
    ...
end;

This is all covered in more detail in Delphi's documentation:
https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Exceptions_(Delphi)

my first example was not compled, sorry for that. I try so many lines.
test example is working in a new created *.dpr
try
Connect;
except
on e: EConnectException do
...
end;
but in my current myapp.dpr it's not working.
so seems there is something wrong in it. I will remove all compiler warnings and come back to you
thanks for hints
